# Linux console Shift + PgUp not working anymore

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-consoles

I run Fedora 24 and sometimes use a virtual console.
(I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to the virtual console, so it's not a terminal in X).
In the past I could use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> to scroll but today it stopped.

In the manpages and in vim the <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> work fine; furthermore the same shortcuts work fine in Xterm.

Does anybody know why I lost the shortcuts to scroll the screen in the virtual consoles?

Comment: Text consoles normally lose the scroll buffer when you switch between them.

Answer (score 15):

Scrollback via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> is no longer supported on console terminals by newer kernels. See this post: [software scrollback support removed](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/the-latest-kernel-release-4175597503/page52.html#post6167719). Alternatives are to use `screen`, `more` or `less`. (Of course, there will be times that the message we wanted to read will have gone past before we were able to run `screen`, `more` or `less`!)

Comment: Of course, a kernel change made in 2020 does not explain a problem that someone was having in 2016.  We will likely never know what the real problem there was.