# Can't scroll up fedora 33 server screen WHY?

Tags: fedora, gnu-screen, console

I install a fedora 33 server OS, and I can't use any key that previously searches on the internet.
any idea?

Comment: All alright, @Artem S. Tashkinov gives the story and reason why.
any SOLUTIONS?

Comment: This answers your question: [Linux console Shift + PgUp not working anymore](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325542/linux-console-shift-pgup-not-working-anymore)

Answer (score 3):

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.9-Drops-Soft-Scrollback

Soft scrollback buffer has been removed because it contained vulnerabilities and no one stepped up to maintain the code.

You can use `screen`, `tmux`, `less` as a workaround but none of them will allow to scroll back your boot messages unfortunately.